# SPSS Statistics GPL Displaying percentage bars for multi-coded variables

Tags: spss

I am trying to create a frequency chart to show the percentages from a multi-response set BDecideCX1 to BDecideCX9, but the percentages are based on the total number of codes rather than the total number of cases. I've tried using a BASE command to repercentage on a different base on the ELEMENT below, but with no success. Any help much appreciated.

```
TEMP.
SELECT IF BDecideCX1>=0.
MRSETS
 /MDGROUP NAME=$temp
 VARIABLES = BDecideCX1 to BDecideCX9
 VALUE=1
 LABEL="Who was involved in deciding how to spend the PE and sport premium?".
GGRAPH
 /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=$temp RESPONSES() [NAME="RESPONSES"]     
    MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO
 /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE TEMPLATE=["TCharts\FreqPurple.SGT"].
 BEGIN GPL
 SOURCE: s = userSource(id("graphdataset"))
 DATA:   temp=col(source(s), name("$temp"), unit.category())
 DATA: responses=col(source(s), name("RESPONSES"))
 SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0))
 GUIDE: text.title(label("Who was involved in deciding how to spend the PE and sport premium? FREQUENCY"))
 GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("%"))
 GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Who was involved in deciding how to spend the PE and sport premium?"))
 ELEMENT: interval(position(summary.percent(temp*responses)))
 END GPL.
```

Comment: You can't do this directly within GPL unfortunately. What I've suggested is to create a new variable that represents the sum, and then you can calculate your own percentages. See [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7d578f9d-9f11-443d-a940-cd271aaff87d&ps=25) for an example.